# /etc/ssh/ssh_config: line 58: Bad configuration option: subsystem

Tags: 14.04, command-line, bash, scripts, ssh

I have a configured the /etc/ssh/ssh_config file as below -

```
# This is the ssh client system-wide configuration file.  See
# ssh_config(5) for more information.  This file provides defaults for
# users, and the values can be changed in per-user configuration files
# or on the command line.

# Configuration data is parsed as follows:
#  1. command line options
#  2. user-specific file
#  3. system-wide file
# Any configuration value is only changed the first time it is set.
# Thus, host-specific definitions should be at the beginning of the
# configuration file, and defaults at the end.

# Site-wide defaults for some commonly used options.  For a comprehensive
# list of available options, their meanings and defaults, please see the
# ssh_config(5) man page.

Host *
#   ForwardAgent no
#   ForwardX11 no
#   ForwardX11Trusted yes
#   RhostsRSAAuthentication no
#   RSAAuthentication yes
#   PasswordAuthentication yes
#   HostbasedAuthentication no
#   GSSAPIAuthentication no
#   GSSAPIDelegateCredentials no
#   GSSAPIKeyExchange no
#   GSSAPITrustDNS no
#   BatchMode no
#   CheckHostIP yes
#   AddressFamily any
#   ConnectTimeout 0
#   StrictHostKeyChecking ask
#   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/identity
#   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
#   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_dsa
#   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_ecdsa
#   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_ed25519
#   Port 22
#   Protocol 2
#   Cipher 3des
#   Ciphers aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc
#   MACs hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160
#   EscapeChar ~
#   Tunnel no
#   TunnelDevice any:any
#   PermitLocalCommand no
#   VisualHostKey no
#   ProxyCommand ssh -q -W %h:%p gateway.example.com
#   RekeyLimit 1G 1h
    SendEnv LANG LC_*
    HashKnownHosts yes
    GSSAPIAuthentication yes

#Subsystem      sftp    /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server
Subsystem       sftp    internal-sftp

Match Group sftp_users
  X11Forwarding no
  AllowTcpForwarding no
  ChrootDirectory %h
  ForceCommand internal-sftp
```

While running one shell script I am getting the below error -

```
/etc/ssh/ssh_config: line 58: Bad configuration option: subsystem
Unsupported Match attribute Group
/etc/ssh/ssh_config line 60: Bad Match condition
lost connection
```

Can someone please help me on this to resolve the issue. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It looks like you have placed a number of SSH **server** config options in the SSH **client** config file - they need to go in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` instead of `/etc/ssh/ssh_config`

Answer (score 1):

Just remove the last lines  beginning with 'Subsystem' from ssh_config.

```
#Subsystem      sftp    /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server
Subsystem       sftp    internal-sftp

Match Group sftp_users
  X11Forwarding no
  AllowTcpForwarding no
  ChrootDirectory %h
  ForceCommand internal-sftp
```

Then you may open sshd_config and uncomment or change settings there.

Comment: Thanks to you. It worked.